# Make 100% of height responsive for any device

Tags: html, css, web-services

How i give 100% height to div when i give **height 100%** (It's not working) then i give **height 100vh** then **min-height 100vh**  but it create extra space and div become more larger than required i also try max-height but not working. i want to give height 100% of element that any any small device it. In this example height is become greater than screen and make a scroll. how i get only 100% with out scroll with out missing any element.

```
<!doctype html>

<div class="header">asas
</div>

<div class="main">
</div>

<div id="footer">


</div>

<style>
.header
{
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background:#000;

    }
.main
{   width:100%;
min-height:100vh;
    background:#C00;

    }
    #footer
    {width:100%;
   height:100px;
    background:#0C3;
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calc()` to take off the values of header and footer:

```css
body {margin:0}
.header {
  height: 60px;
  background: #000;
}
.main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 160px);
  background: #C00;
}
#footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: #0C3;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">asas
</div>

<div class="main">
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this 
you have to give the parent always a defined height if not it is not working if you work with %

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #000;
}
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 160px); /* here you calculate the 100% minus the 60px of the header and 100px of the footer*/
  background: #C00;
}
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #0C3;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="header">asas
</div>

<div class="main">
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need [Internet Explorer](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) then you could use `flexbox`

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: cyan
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="main">Content</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```